# How to make Two Different WebViews in the same view controller, so that they do not share ANY data?

Tags: objective-c, webview, uiwebview

Currently, when I add two webviews in the same view controller, they share data. For instance if one web view logs in to a website, the other web view is also logged in to the web site, how can I stop this from happening? 
Thank you

Comment: Its new problem to me. But trying to solve.
Did u checked the delegate method of UIWebView? May be it's getting called twice  - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView.
As long as I think it's a problem of cookie by ur HTTP requests!

Comment: Yes, they are linked to different delagates

Answer (score 0):

set frame size of two different webview on the initialize or whenever loading time

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGRect frame = webView_first.frame;

    frame.size.height = 5.0f;

    webView_first.frame = frame;
    webView_second.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the answer is irrelevant to the question. Can you explain how it is relevant to the question being asked ?